# Single digits in month is creating a discrepancy in date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have two cells that have a date field. I have code to delete records based on dates.

**Scenario 1:** (Working)
Column has the date as 30/04/2020 10:00:00 (dd/mm/yyyy format).

**Scenario 2:** (discrepancy)
Column has the date as 01/05/2020 10:00:00 (dd/mm/yyyy format).
My code is treating it as 01JAN2020.

**Sample code:**

```vb
a=worksheets("Sheet1").cells(row,col).value ' captures value in the required column
b=format (date-1,"DD-MM-YYYY") ' Captures yesterdays date for comparison purpose

'This is to convert the required column format
' to the format that we are comparing the value with
c=format(a,"DD-MM-YYYY")

if (b <> c) then
    msgbox("This is an invalid record")
else
    msgbox("Valid")
end if
```

The code works when the date is 30/04/2020 10:00:00 which is treated as 30-APR.

But 01/05/2020 10:00:00 is treated as 01-JAN and the comparison goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**
I have tried using the `SPLIT` and `CDATE` combination and that did solve my purpose.

```
a1=split(worksheets("Sheet1").cells(row,col).value,"/") ' captures value in the required column
a=cdate(a(1) & "/" & a(0) & "/" &a(2))
b=format (date-1,"DD-MM-YYYY") ' Captures yesterdays date for comparison purpose
c=format(a,"DD-MM-YYYY") 'This is to convert the required column format to the format that we are comparing the value with

if (b <> c) then
 msgbox("This is an invalid record")
else
msgbox("Valid")
end if
```

Answer (score 3):

If both dates are truly Valid excel dates, then converting to string format just adds unnecessary noise.

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col).Value ' captures value in the required column
b = Date - 1


If (a <> b) Then
 MsgBox ("This is an invalid record")
Else
MsgBox ("Valid")
End If
```

should work.

If the dates are NOT valid dates, then you need to correct that problem.

The issue you describe is usually created by incorrectly opening a text/csv file that has dates in a format different from your Windows Regional Settings.  The "fix" is to import the data, so you can tell Excel the proper format at the time of importation.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the data that is imported in that excel is a not a date format..its a string and that could be the reason..We may have to work on to get on this as string and do some VBA to handle it..any ideas on it ? I have an idea of implementing `SPLIT` and use the `CDATE` on top of it..I am doing some trail and error currently on it whilst I seek an expert advise in the forum..

Comment: What is the source of the data?

Comment: Also, how are you getting the data into Excel?  Are all the dates in the Excel column Text, or are some Text and some "real dates"?  (and do you know how to tell the difference?)

Comment: We have a system where the report is extracted and is then used as input to the sheet here...Its a copy of the data form that source generated report to the sheet where the VBA is in...yeah I can see the difference of the texts and real dates by right clicking to format cells and confirmed that they are general and not dates.

Comment: @user2075017 A better method -- Text dates will usually be left-justified, and,. more importantly, if you format them as "date" or "number", they won't change in appearance in the worksheet cells.  If ALL of them are text, you can use the `text-to-columns` wizard (either on the worksheet, or in VBA) to convert them.  If SOME are real dates and others not, you will need to provide more information about the **extraction - input** process.

Comment: I had used a similar concept of text to columns and fixed the issue. I had used the `SPLIT` function and then applied a `CDATE` function on it. I will post my answer in this forum.